# (SOLVED) Why is a 'vector subscript out of range' message appearing on this counting sort algorithm? (SOLVED)

Tags: c++, outofrangeexception, counting-sort

EDIT: I've solved the issue! It had nothing to do with the function itself. I initially used a vector for this function, and the cout statement I used to check the function in main() still called the vector, not the array. A simple mistake, but I appreciate the help!

Hey! I'm currently in college learning data structures, and for our final project, we're tasked with creating multiple sorting algorithms to sort 500,000 randomly generated numbers between 1 - 9,999,999 that have been defined in a text file. I'm currently trying to work on a counting sort, and I keep getting the #include vector line 1553 error 'vector subscript out of range'. I've debugged this function all the way to the last for-loop. Everything seems to work perfectly fine, so I'm assuming it has to do with somewhere in this final piece, but I'd prefer to not have to manually go through 500,000 cycles, so if anyone can see what I've done wrong, I'd like to know.

I also allocated this data on the heap because stack allocation creates a memory overload.

I apologize if this is a low-level question, but I'd love some help, as this project means a lot to me and to my grade. Thank you!

```
    void countingSort(int numberArray[], int SIZE)
    {
    // Initializer for dynamically-allocated array used to hold the sorted data in the array
        int* sortedArray = new int[SIZE];
    
    // Initializes all values in sortedArray to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        sortedArray[i] = 0;

    // Initializer for variable used to hold the maximum value in the original data
    int max = 0;

    // Finds the max in numberArray
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (numberArray[i] > max)
            max = numberArray[i];
    }

    // Create an array to store the amount of times each number in numberArray is used
    int* countArray = new int[max + 1];

    // Initialize all indexes of countArray to 0
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
    {
        countArray[i] = 0;
    }

    // When a number is present in numberArray, increase its number of appearances in countArray by one
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
        countArray[numberArray[i]]++;

    // Find the total frequency in the count array
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
        countArray[i] += countArray[i - 1];

    // Store the sorted values into a sorted array
    // Decrease the total count number
    for (int i = SIZE - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        sortedArray[countArray[numberArray[i]] - 1] = numberArray[i];
        countArray[numberArray[i]]--;
    }

    // Store the sorted array in the original numberArray
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        numberArray[i] = sortedArray[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int* SIZE = new int;
    *SIZE = 500000;
.
(*code for other functions*)
.
countingSort(numberArray, *SIZE);
cout << "\n" << numberList[0] << "\t" << numberList[499999] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Add debug output that would give you the information you would obtain by stepping through it with a debugger. If you just run it under debugger (without stepping through it) does it no show the stack trace where the error happen? Also, try reducing your input data set, while keeping the issue reproducing to simplify debugging. I see `countArray[numberArray[i]]++` and `sortedArray[countArray[numberArray[i]] - 1]` - those two are obvious suspects, especially if all your arrays are of size of 500k, while numbers are up to a million.

Comment: Wait, I don't see a single vector here...

Comment: To state the obvious, one of your array accesses is going out of bounds.   When a programmer believes there is no error, and a program crashes, it is usually the programmer who is mistaken.    Step through with a debugger to find it.     Oh, get out of the habit of using `new` for everything.   C++ does not require that.  It is usually terrible practice (and you are demonstrating that in spades).

Comment: @n0rd this is exactly what was confusing me. It was only in reading this that I realized I had not changed the cout statement directly after the function call to show that it was working. This function works perfectly, but I had originally used vectors in place of arrays and forgot to change my cout statements when making the switch. It was a simple mistake, but I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Peter thanks for the help! Could you more explicitly describe what my error is in the overuse of new? I originally tried allocating these arrays without new, but to my understanding, in C++ that allocated them on the stack, something the compiler warned me was causing a memory overflow due to the arrays containing such a large number of elements. Is there something about 'new' that I'm missing and that I should avoid in the future?

Comment: Are you familiar with `std::vector`?

Comment: @beargrammer   My point is that the C++ standard library provides facilities that can manage arbitrary sized collections of elements (including `std::vector` which manages a dynamically allocated array).  Using standard containers is a much less error prone way of doing such things than by using `new` and `delete` directly.   Too many bad teachers and textbooks introduce beginners to the `new`/`delete` bad habit and beginners then come to believe they can do better that way than using (say) `std::vector` - and they are wrong in that belief.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am! That was the issue with my code, as I found last night. I originally used a vector to solve this problem, and the statement I used to check if the data had been sorted still called for the original vector, not the array I replaced it with, hence the error. Thank you!

Comment: @Peter thank you! I originally used a vector but decided to switch to an array with a defined size because this project uses a data set with a fixed number of elements. Do you believe a vector would actually be the more intelligent approach, say to make this code more modular (or potentially another reason)?

Comment: @n0rd, sorry I thought I responded last night. This was the comment that solved my issue. I initially used a vector for this program but decided to switch to an array because the data set had a fixed amount of elements. The function itself was correct, but the cout statement I used to check if the data had been sorted still called the vector (as I had forgotten to switch the name), and because the vector never changed from a size of 0, I got the error. It was a small mistake, but I appreciate your helping me notice it nonetheless! Thank you.